# Can't retrieve just names from the database using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like to get the value of all the `name` keys inside my database. I only have one key (field) which is the "name" key in each document of the db. here is the code. The code I need help with the most is towards the bottom starting with

`user.find({}, 'name', function(err, users){`...

when i use `user.name` I get undefined.

when i use `var html = "All users" + users + '<br>';`  I get the list of objects/ documents. I just want the value of the name

goal: When user puts in their name and submits. Next page displays all the names in the db including the one that was just entered.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Company');

var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String
})

var user = mongoose.model('emp', Schema);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var html = '<form action="/" method = "post">' + 
                'Enter your name:' + 
                '<input type = "text" name = "userName" placeholder= "...." />'+
                '<br>' + 
                '<button type = "submit">Submit</button>' +
                '</form>';
    res.send(html);
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var html = "";
    var userName = req.body.userName;

    new user({
        name : req.body.userName
    }).save(function(err, doc){
     if(err){
        res.json(err);
     } else{
        user.findOne({'name' : userName }, 'name', function(err, user){
            if(err) return handleError(err);
    var html = "Hello: " + user.name + '.<br>' +
                '<a href="/">Try again</a>';

        });
     }

     // here is the code I need help with
     user.find({}, 'name', function(err, users){
        var html = "All users" + users.name + '<br>';
        res.send(html);
     });



    })
});
var server = app.listen(80, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `'name'` selector to your `find` call limits the properties of the documents in the `users` array, but it's still an array of document objects, not strings.  To map that into an array of just the `name` strings you can call JavaScript's [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function that's available on all arrays:

```
 user.find({}, 'name', function(err, users){
    var html = "All users" + users.map(function(doc) {
        return doc.name + '<br>';
    });
    res.send(html);
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, this works. I just want to see if there are other ways to do this  before I close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know underscore has a method called pluck that will do what you want to get all name objects out of a collection of objects. Mongo models lists may come with that method, but I'm not sure.

```
_.pluck([{name: 'jo', hair: 'brown'}, {name: 'cody', hair: 'blond'}],'name')

=> ['jo','cody']
```

You could give it a try on the mongo collection.